# converting JSON time and date format and location format

Tags: json, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm currently getting a JSON response back with timezone, and date in a utc format. I'd like to switch it to a more readable format. The timezone - "America/Los_Angeles" is a tad bit tricky. Any ideas particularly on how to get to to just show the city? Thank you in advance for any pointers

```
Plan_it.Start(timezone: "America/Los_Angeles", utc: "2018-06-27T03:00:00Z", local: Optional("2018-06-26T20:00:00"))
```

When I print these to the console I get the output as so. I would like to get an output like - Basically I need to reformat the output, was my original question.

(May 26, 2018 10:30 and Los Angeles.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    eventNameLbl.text = detailedEvent?.name.html
    eventStartTimeLbl.text = detailedEvent?.start.local
    eventAddressLbl.text = detailedEvent?.start.timezone
    eventDescriptionLbl.text = detailedEvent?.description.text
```

> output//Optional("2018-05-26T20:30:00")
>      output//Optional("America/Los_Angeles")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `DateFormatter`. You first need to parse the local string to a `Date` using the provided timezone. Then you can format that date as desired.

```
if let dateStr = detailedEvent?.start.local, let timezone = detailedEvent?.start.timezone {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezone)
    if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMddyyyyHHmmVVV")
        df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezone)
        let dateCity = df.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

Or you can split it out:

```
if let dateStr = detailedEvent?.start.local, let timezone = detailedEvent?.start.timezone {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezone)
    if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
       let df = DateFormatter()
       df.dateStyle = .medium
       df.timeStyle = .short
       df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezone)
       let localdate = df.string(from: date)
       df.dateFormat = "VVV"
       let city = df.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: im actually getting issues with this answer. im getting an error in the first format for let dateCity = df.string(from: date) .. The error reads 'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Comment: I was assuming that `local` was already a `Date` but it appears it is still a `String`. Give me a few minutes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update man! So that runs and gives me the correct output within the counsel. but when i try and set a text label outside of this block of code, it does not let me.. hmmm - im playing around with the code now to try and solve it

Comment: Nevermind i definitely figured out where i was confused. Thanks again!